# System.DllNotFoundException

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, mysql-connector

I have entity framework database first based mvc asp.net project. I have installed EF6 and MySql but still getting this error

> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6,
>   Version=6.10.8.0, Culture=neutral
>
> System.DllNotFoundException:
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6,
>   Version=6.10.8.0

Comment: Do you have MySQL connector installed on this system?

Comment: I have MySQL connector. Infact other projects is running perfectly

Comment: Can you check project bitness settings? Platform/platform targer/prefer 32-bit setting? It might be bitness mismatch between this project and the connector.

Comment: I checked and It is any CPU.